# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent nodejs

Tags: node.js

When I post the new event, it is created and the sort function works properly as well but when I call the search function, I want it to compare it with both name and location but it doesn't compare with location. Is there any way to check both? Also after sorting or search when I want to create a new event, it gives me the below error. I am new to this. Help me with both the errors.
**server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config=require('./config');
var app= express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var lodash= require('lodash');
var underscore= require('underscore');
//var User=require('./database/user')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db',function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected!");
    }
});
//res.json({message:"     " })
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); //if false then parse only strings
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));//log all the requests to the console
var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express,underscore,lodash);
app.use('/api',api);
app.get('*',function(req,res){
  //  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});   // * means any route

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("The server is running");
    }
});
```

**api.js**

```
var User= require('../models/user');
var Event=require('../models/event');
var config=require('../../config');

var secret=config.secretKey;

module.exports=function(app,express,underscore,lodash) {
    var api = express.Router();
    // app.use()

    api.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'User created!'
            });
        });

    });
    api.get('/users', function (req, res) {
        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
           res.json(users);
        });
    });
/*    api.get('search',function(req,res){
        search: req.body.search;
        if(search==)
    });*/


    api.post('/eventfeed', function (req, res) {
        var event = new Event({
            name: req.body.name,
            location: req.body.location,
            description: req.body.description,
            price: req.body.price,
            rating: req.body.rating
        });

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Event created!'
            });
        });
    });
    api.get('/event', function (req, res) {
        Event.find({}, function (err, event) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(event);
        });
    });
api.get('/sortby_price', function (req, res) {
    Event.find({}, function (err, events) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }

        var ascending = true;//change to false for descending
        events.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a.price - b.price) * (ascending ? 1 : -1);
                });

            res.json(events);
         });
    });
    api.get('/sortby_rating', function (req, res){
        Event.find({}, function (err, events) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            var ascending = true;//change to false for descending
            events.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a.rating - b.rating) * (ascending ? 1 : -1);
            });

            res.json(events);
        });
    });

    api.post('/search', function (req, res) {

        Event.find({'name':req.body.name},function (err, events) {

            if (err)
                return res.json(err);
            else
                res.json(events);
        });
           Event.find({'location':req.body.name},function (err, events) {

                if (err)
                    return res.json(err);
                else
                    res.json(events);

                console.log("name is" + req.body.name);
            });

        });

 return api;

}
```

**error**

```
http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\app\routes\api.js:209:25)
    at c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:177:19
    at c:\Users\MY LAPY\WebstormProjects\Main\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `/api/search` route, you are performing two `Event.find()`s in parallel and inside the callback for each of those, you're responding to the same http request.

So you need to either:

1. Have a third callback that is called only when *both* `Event.find()`s have completed, so you respond to the request only once there, OR
2. Perform the `Event.find()`s sequentially by placing one inside the callback of the other and only respond to the request inside the inner-most callback, OR
3. Only perform *one* `Event.find()` by using [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to check either field. For example:

   ```
   api.post('/search', function (req, res) {
     Event.find({
       $or: [ {'name': req.body.name}, {'location': req.body.name} ]
     }, function (err, events) {
       if (err)
         return res.json(err);
       else
         res.json(events);
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me :)